# PHPStorm: Disable Auto Opening of File transfer tool window

Tags: ide, settings, phpstorm

I'm using PHPStorm 10, every first save after the opening PHPStorm the File transfer tool windows show up, telling me that the file is being auto uploaded.

I've tried all type of settings, without good results: the file transfer window keep showing up at the first save. How can i disable this behavior?

This is the tool window:
[File Transfer tool window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ockbP.png)

Comment: You could drag tool window's border until it goes under existing Interface. You cannot avoid it from opening, but it will surely never bother you again. Should you ever need it back, you can right-click on `File Transfer` and select another view option (Window, for example).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open *Tools > Deployment > Options* and change **Operations logging** to "Errors only".

Answer (score 2):

There is no such option in `Settings/Preferences`.

Just close the window (minimize it) and it will not show up again for this session (only notifications, which you can disable if so desired via `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Notifications` -- look for "Web deployment" entries).

Comment: I don't understand why a negative vote has been issued: this is still true for the latest PHP storm version (2019.1)

Comment: @ErenorPaz Some people just do not like "it cannot be done" or "I know that it cannot be done, but I was looking for some solution and not confirmation" answers...

Answer (score 1):

If you change the View Mode to `Undock` and drag the inner edge of the File Transfer window outside the viewport, it will effectively be disabled. This is not very elegant and I hope JetBrains gives us a setting to disable this soon.

To see the File Transfer window again, right-click on File Transfer and select another view option such as `Dock Pinned`.

As of PHPStorm 2019.1.2. *Thanks to Erenor's comment for the inspiration.*

**Edit:** Ástþór's answer does work provided none of the transfers are throwing errors. Due to the way a server is set up on one of my projects, it always gives a benign error, which makes the File Transfer window pop up.

Comment: If you have an error related to timestamps - just disable "Preserve files timestamps" checkbox at Tools > Deployment > Options.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll use this for now.

Comment: Ástþór suggestion worked for me, too, although I found the option "Preserve files timestamps" in Build, Execution, Deployment -> Deployment -> Options. Thank you,  Ástþór!